# get only characters before integer python

Tags: python

I have a string `paragraph112para` and I have to print only `paragraph`. How to do it?

I tried:

```
word1 = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", st))
```

but it returns `"paragraph para"`

Comment: You're using 'findall'. Did you mean store everything up to the first number, or just strip numerics out?

Comment: How about this: word1 = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", st)[0]

Comment: @CorleyBrigman yes,I have to store everything up to first number.

Answer (score 4):

Using `re.findall()` will find all of the matches, to get just the first match you should use `re.search()`:

```
word1 = re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]+", st).group(0)
```

Comment: ...or `re.search(r"[^\d]+", st).group(0)` if there are other characters than letters before the digits.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [positive lookahead](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+(?=\d)', 'paragraph112para')
['paragraph']
```

This looks for one or more letters followed by a digit (but does not include the digit in the match).